# overload operator = with two arguments in c++

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

i'm writing a class like this :

```
class Digit
{
    private :
        int *ref;
    public :
        Digit (int a) : ref(&a) {}
        int get_val ()
        {
            return (*ref);
        }
        Digit operator= (int &a)
        {
            if (a < 0 || a > 9)
                throw "invalid digit assignment.";
            (*ref) = a;
            return (*this);
        }
    };
```

so if someone define a digit ,he can not assign value more than 9 or less than 0 to it.
the problem is, i also want to define another = operator, that he can assign a Digit to some value too.
i tried something like this :

```
int operator= (int &a, Digit &d)
{
    a = d.get_value();
    return a;
}
```

but i get some error : `'int operator=(int&, Digit&)' must be a nonstatic member function`

how can i fix this? how can i overload operator = with 2 arguments?

Comment: Why is `ref` a *pointer*? (It's also invalid as soon as the constructor returns.)

Comment: Instead of thinking "how can I overload the assignment operator", think "how can I implicitly convert a `Digit` to an `int`".

Comment: @molbdnilo i had to write a class with [] operator that returns digit so we can use it like : a[10] = 5; (and some member of a changes to 5.)

Comment: @timaru i think so. so there is no way to do that?

Comment: @iambb5445 -- Seems you need to properly document what operations you're looking for.  Your current code has multiple issues, one being using a pointer to a temporary, the second is the unorthodox usage of `operator =` returning a new object instead of `*this` by reference, i.e. returning a `Date&`, not `Date`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right about pointer to temporary, thanks for mentioning this. but i can't understand the second issue. can you explain it with more details please?

Comment: @iambb5445 `Digit d(param);  d = 5;`  Since `d` has already been constructed, an assignment should just assign to the already constructed object and return that already constructed object by reference.  Anything else is counter-intuitive (returning a new object, as your code attempts to do).

Comment: Standart says: `An assignment operator shall be implemented by a non-static member function with exactly one parameter`. So you can't implement it as free beenary operator. Use implicit/explicite convertion 'operator int()'

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i understand now. thanks a lot! i think i can fix this by changing it to : Digit& operator= (int a)

Comment: @iambb5445 -- Yes, that should fix the return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really need may be `operator int()`.

```
class Digit {
   operator int() { return get_val(); }
};
```

Then you can write `int a = d;` assuming `d` is of `class Digit`.

Comment: That will solve the immediate issue, but as soon as the program becomes more involved, where `int` and `Digit` are being passed and returned, casting operators are more of a headache.  There could be "silent" conversions going on where you least expect it to happen.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That can be solved by making the operator `explicit`.

Comment: thanks a lot! that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to get the value of the Digit as an int, if I understand correctly.

You aren't going to use operator = for that, because operator = is for assigning *to* the class. You want to extract a value from the class.

Your method:

```
 int get_val ()
 {
    return (*ref);
 }
```

Already does this. However, it should be

```
int get_val () const
{
    return (*ref);
}
```

because it does not change the value of any class members.

Usage would be:

```
int main()
{   
    Digit digit(5);
    int myInt = digit.get_value();
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to implicitly convert Digit to an int, you can use

```
operator int()
{
    return get_val();
}
```

which is just a shortcut. Without that operator, you'd do something like:

```
#include <iostream>

void Print(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{   
    Digit digit(5);
    Print(digit.get_value());

    return 0;
}
```

but with the operator, you tell the compiler the Digit class may be treated (converted) like an int:

```
#include <iostream>

void Print(int x)
{
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{   
    Digit digit(5);
    Print(digit);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i'm writing a header file, and someone else is going to write main function.